# JMeter: How to access loop counter inside ForEach Controller?

Tags: jmeter

I have a ForEach controller in JMeter.

How can I access counter of a loop inside this controller (through variable) and then use it for creating new variables?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put [Counter configuration element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) inside ForEach Controller and check attributes "Track Counter Independently for each User" and "Reset counter on each Thread Group Iteration"

Answer (score 1):

No need for a counter.

The loop index is built into JMeter 4.0 and later - see [Jmeter/Groovy: getting iteration number without reference to Beanshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51815125/jmeter-groovy-getting-iteration-number-without-reference-to-beanshell)

Jmeter bug [61802](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61802) - Loop / ForEach Controller should expose a variable for current iteration

For example if your ForEachController is named ForEachCard then this will get you the loop index (starting at zero).

```
def cardIndex = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("__jm__ForEachCard__idx"));
```

This would get you the ordinal and then obtain the associated value from a previous JSON Extractor using capture all ( Match# = -1 )

```
def cardOrdinal = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("__jm__ForEachCard__idx")) + 1;
def currCardBalance = vars.get("cardBalance_" + cardOrdinal )
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used this ForEach controller in my script and I got the answer.
First create a regular expression for the value you are looking for and then [add a ForEach controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBINw.png)

With the above image you will get a clear idea about it.